Saving Excel file to Sharepoint failing
I'm getting an error with this code when trying to save to Sharepoint. Code is longer, but including relevant pieces.
Dim fso As Object
Dim template As Workbook
Dim TempPath As String  'path is set with folder picker

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
currentname = fso.GetBaseName(ThisWorkbook.Name)

Set template = Workbooks.Open(TempPath)
DoEvents

If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Path, "/") > 0 Then 'check if it's saving to Sharepoint
urlpath = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Path, " ", "%20")
urlname = Replace(currentname, " ", "%20")
Savename = urlpath & "/" & urlname & "_New" & ".xlsm"
Else
Savename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & currentname & "_New" & ".xlsm"
End If

currentformat = template.FileFormat
template.SaveAs Filename:=Savename, FileFormat:=currentformat

The code works when 'ThisWorkbook' is in the system file library, but errors when file is in Sharepoint.  I recorded a 'Save' macro and the system shows filename as (example) https:// "companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/team_data/Shared%20Documents/folder%20location"
If I assign Savename with that address specifically, it works.  So the problem seems to be with using the concatenation of the workbook path and name. If I display the concatenated name in a message box, it appears to be the exact same as the direct path. I can't figure out what the issue is with the concatenation. The workbook.path for sharepoint returns with spaces instead of %20.  I added the 'replace' code to add the %20 to match how the save macro showed it.

unresolved.  I changed it to save to a local drive instead of the Sharepoint as a workaround.

This works OK for me:
Sub SPTester()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim template As Workbook, newname, Savename
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    newname = fso.GetBaseName(ThisWorkbook.Name) & "_New.xlsm"
    
    Set template = Workbooks.Open("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1/TestLibrary/test2.xlsm")
    DoEvents
    
    Savename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & newname 'windows won't complain about "/"
    
    Debug.Print "saving as..." & vbLf & Savename
    
    template.SaveAs Filename:=Savename, FileFormat:=template.FileFormat
End Sub


Thanks, I tried to adapt to my code but getting same error.  I don't know if it matters, but in your code, 'template' is opening a book from Sharepoint and saving it back there.  In mine, template will be a file pulled from the computer's file library that I am trying to save into Sharepoint.

It should work the same way with a local template.  What's the exact error you're getting?

Method Save As of object_workbook failed

Are you logged in to SharePoint and/or Office 365?

Both. I've modified it to save to a local drive as a workaround until I can get more time to troubleshoot.   I saw one post stating there was an error if file name was too long, idk if thats true, but it could be the case here if so.  The SP is a large site with a long file path to get where it needs to go.

Depending on your use case - you could try syncing the folder and saving the file to the local sync location.

Would you tell me whether your issue has been resolved or have any update? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.
